# Is it possible to launch a third party app from my flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to launch a third-party app from my flutter but I’m not getting anywhere. In this case, I am trying to open the app “Amazon Alexa” by clicking on a raised button in Flutter. Can anyone help me out?

I tried to use url_launcher but it didn’t work out with third-party apps.

Comment: By `Amazon Alexa`, do you mean `https://alexa.amazon.com` ?

Comment: And are you getting any error while using `url_launcher` ?

Comment: I am not getting any error at all. It's just not opening the app. In this case, "Amazon Alexa" was just an example.

I am trying to open an app, which has no website. Lets take as example the game "MARIO RUN". Is there any way to tell the launcher, that it has to open a specific App?

Answer (score 0):

yes, some packages are available but the issue is, these are still in the early stages.
so for that, you need to move to the native side.